# QMake/QtCreatir What's the good strategy to copy a binary to a given location

Tags: android, qt-creator, qmake

I'm compiling a library for Android using QtCreator. After it's built, I need it to be copied to a specific location.

I was using QtCreator 4.0.3 with Qt 5.6 and NDK r11b

I'm now migrating my code to QtCreator 4.8.0 with Qt 5.12 and NDK r18b

With QtCreator 4.0.3 I used to have:

```
DESTDIR = <path to the place where I wish the binary to be copied>
```

And it worked perfectly (.so file was copied after it was generated)

With QtCreator 4.8.0 I get the error:

```
move libsde3p_cppunit-g.so <path to the place where I wish the binary to be copied>\libsde3p_cppunit-g.so
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, move libsde3p_cppunit-g.so <path to the place where I wish the binary to be copied>\libsde3p_cppunit-g.so, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
```

I see that when this error is reported `<my build folder>\build-cppunit-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\libsde3p_cppunit-g.so` exists while `<my build folder>\build-cppunit-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\android-build\libs\armeabi-v7a\libsde3p_cppunit-g.so` does not yet. And I know QtCreator finally copies the lib from this first location to the second. So most likely, it tries to copy the library from the wrong location.

I tried some other alternatives:

Tried `QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy...` this is apparently never executed (`QMAKE_POST_LINK = djdkdk` does not report any error).

Tried custom targets:

```
custom_copy_step.target = foo.h
custom_copy_step.commands = $(COPY_FILE) $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)\lib$${TARGET}.so $$shell_path(<path to the place where I wish the binary to be copied>
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += custom_copy_step
POST_TARGETDEPS += foo.h
```

This time it fails with error:

```
copy /y <my build folder>\build-cppunit-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv7-Debug\libsde3p_cppunit-g.so <path to the place where I wish the binary to be copied>
Le fichier sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
make: *** [foo.h] Error 1
```

And I confirm the lib file is not present on disk, so looks like the command is executed before the .so is actually generated.

What instructions should I add to my .pro file to have the output .so file be copied to a specific location?

Answer (score 0):

Could make it work with `QMAKE_POST_LINK` (needs a `+=` instead of `=`):

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $(COPY_FILE) $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)\lib$${TARGET}.so $$shell_path(<path to the place where I wish the binary to be copied>)
```